# Как передать цену и ид товара через переменную в WordPress + WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

Возможно ли передать ид и цену товара через переменную в код для динамического ремаркетинга.

```
<script>
  var dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'view_item',
    'value': '**передать цену через переменную**',
    'items':[{
      'id': '**передать id товара через переменнуб**',
      'google_business_vertical': 'retail'                  
    }]
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Вставьте в footer.php следующий фрагмент

```
<?php if (is_plugin_active("woocommerce/woocommerce.php") && is_product() ) { ?>

<?php global $product; ?>

<?php 
       $product_id = $product->get_id();
            
       if ($product->product_type == 'variable') {
                
            $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
                
            $count = count($available_variations)-1;
                
            $variation_id = $available_variations[$count]['variation_id']; 
 
            $variable_product1= new \WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );
                
            $price = $variable_product1 ->get_price();
                
        } else {
            $price = $product->get_price();
        } 

?>

<script>
  var dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'view_item',
    'value': '<?php echo $price; ?>',
    'items':[{
      'id': '<?php echo $product_id; ?>',
      'google_business_vertical': 'retail'                  
    }]
  });
</script>

<?php } ?>
```